# mysql sequence number by value coloumn (query UPDATE)

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sequence

example:
I have a table with the columns

```
______________________
|field_id|Code|seq_num|
|   1    |  a |   1   |
|   1    |  a |   2   |
|   1    |  a |   3   |
|   2    |  a |   4   |
|   2    |  a |   5   |
|   3    |  a |   6   |
|   3    |  a |   7   |
|   3    |  a |   8   |
```

how to query it, so sequence number look like this

```
 _____________________
|field_id|Code|seq_num|
|   1    |  a |   1   |
|   1    |  a |   2   |
|   1    |  a |   3   |
|   2    |  a |   1   |
|   2    |  a |   2   |
|   3    |  a |   1   |
|   3    |  a |   2   |
|   3    |  a |   3   |
```

please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to get the minimum sequence for the field:

```
select t.field_id, t.code,
       (seq_num - min_seqnum + 1) as seqnum
from t join
     (select field_id, min(seq_num) as min_seq_num
      from t
      group by field_id
     ) f
     on t.field_id = f.field_id;
```

You can also do this using variables, if you don't trust the current sequence numbers to have no gaps:

```
select . . .,
       (@rn := if(@f = field_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@f := field_id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as seq_no
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by field_id, seq_no
    ) t cross join
    (select @f := '', @rn := 0) params;
```